# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value xxx to data type int error

Tags: sql-server

I need to take data between certain dates. But I get the following error.

AdsDateStarted : 03/18/2010 01:51:38.000 AM
AdsDateENded   : 09/13/2010 05:00:00.000 PM

formatdate function converts today's date to 3/22/2010 format.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Ads"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE AdsActive = 1 AND AdsAreasID = "& rtt &" AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AdsDateStarted, 101) <= "& formatdate(Date()) &" AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AdsDateEnded, 101) >= "& formatdate(Date()) &""
Set kdFonksiyon = objConn.Execute(SQL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use DateTime type parameters, please, and do not put together the date and time as a string.
- If you HAVE to do that, use the international form that is accepted everywhree: 2010-03-22

Your problem is most likely different locales between client and server. You format as 3/22 and the server understands "day 3 of the 22nd month".

This is bypassed by using parameters of the language neutral iso form, as indicated above.

Comment: No, the problem is that the date is not parsed as a date at all, but as a numeric expression. Se my answer.

Answer (score 2):

THe reason is that you have forgotten the apostrophes around the dates, so you get an expression like `3/22/2010` instead of a date literal like `'3/22/2010'`. The expression evaluates to an int value, so the database tries to convert the varchar values to int values also in order to compare them.

Instead of inserting the date in the query as a string, you should use parameters. Then you don't have to bother with apostrophes, but more importantly you don't have to guess what date format the database might accept.

As you use the dates as strings, there is no problem with parsing the strings to dates as the code is written now, but as you have chosen a date format that is not comparable as strings, your comparison will not work properly. If you want to compare dates as strings, you have to use an ISO 8601 format like 2010-03-22 that is comparable as strings, or preferrably compare the dates as proper dates, which is faster. (Even a lot faster if an index can be used.)

Comment: Possibly yes. I overlooked the ' issue.

Answer (score 1):

One of the immediate problems is that you need to put single quotes around the date values you are concatenating into the SQL string. Also, try to avoid any datetime conversion issues by using a standard ISO format like: yyyy-mm-dd

I would however strongly recommend you parameterise the query instead of building it up dynamically like this. So for example...

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Ads WHERE AdsActive=1 AND AdsAreasID = @rtt AND....."
```

And then pass in the values as parameters to the query. This will help with performance (execution plan reuse) and security (helps guard against SQL injection).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server recognizes 'yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss' as a valid date time and lets you compare in this format. So if your formatDateTime function returns date in yyyyMMdd format that would do. You do not require to do a CONVERT on AdsDateStarted & AdsDateEnded.

Example:

`SELECT * FROM Ads WHERE AdsDateStarted > '20100101' AND AdsDateEnded <= '20100321 11:59:59'`

This query would retrieve all the records matching the date condition.